# Dark Skeen for TinyMCE version 5

Tags: tinymce, skins

please tell me where I can find dark Skins for TinyMCE version 5.

All other skins I've found don't have a dark theme:
material-classic, material-outline, bootstrap, fabric, fluent, borderless, small, jam, naked, outside, snow.

[Skins:](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/enterprise/premium-skins-and-icon-packs/)

Found the Oxide-dark skin, but it's too blue.

Answer (score 0):

Added a dark content css skin
A dark CSS definition for content_css has been added to compliment the dark user interface skin.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/release-notes/release-notes51/#addedadarkcontentcssskin

or

https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/dark-mode-tinymce-rich-text-editor/

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not find this! A particularly good blog article.